# How do I make a condition where if a user doesn't input an integer, it comes up with an error message?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to code in a condition where if a user doesn't input an integer, it comes up with an error message. I'm using if statements to generate this. How would I do this??

```
Age=int(input("What is your age in years?"))

if Age>20 and Age<150:
    print("You are an adult")
elif Age>20 and Age>=150:
    print("Not a valid age")
elif Age<20:
    print("still a teenager")
```

If someone inputted £ as their age, is it possible for the message to print as "Invalid number. Please try again." ?

I've tried to recode it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it should look like:

```
Age=input("What is your age in years?")
try:
   x = int(Age)
   if Age>20 and Age<150:
    print("You are an adult")
elif Age>20 and Age>=150:
    print("Not a valid age")
elif Age<20:
    print("still a teenager")
except ValueError:
   print("Input not valid!")
```

It trys to convert the String into a Int if that doesnt work the user didnt input a valid Number.